# How to know how many users logged in using aws cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Hi I am using AWS cognito user pool.

Now i want to know how many users has logged in today. So how do i get the list of the users who has logged in today.

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/metrics-for-cognito-user-pools.html) ?

Comment: @amitd But i just want to see how many users signed in today. I dont want to use any api. Is it possible to see it in cloud watch?

Comment: You have few options (1) Use [AdminListUserAuthEvents](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminListUserAuthEvents.html) API or specific programming language SDK API, you have to call this in loop for users. even though this is not a efficient way but one of the way. (2) Use [AWS CloudTrail and Amazon S3 bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/02/amazon-cognito-user-pools-now-supports-logging-for-all-api-calls-with-aws-cloudtrail/) as suggested by AWS, then read/parse these events from AWS S3 using automation/programming logic.

Comment: @amitd is it possible for you to give some examples. Actually i wend inside cloud trail but i dont see any logs for the same

Comment: Can someone help me on this